# Update content of a web page asynchronously

Tags: spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I am building a website using Spring MVC and Thymeleaf. So far, all the graphic components get refreshed only after the user interacted with the web UI. I want to display information after getting some other events that have not been initiated by the web UI (Just like facebook does with notifications). Besides simple notification messages, I would like to display the live output of the execution of a batch script (Maybe this is much more difficult).

I would appreciate any help that puts me in the right direction.

Comment: Have you looked into websocket?

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, it seems to be what I am looking for, however it does not look simple. I will give it a shot and evaluate if the project is worth it.

Answer (score 1):

Easiest way to do it would be to expose an endpoint within MVC which queries profile information, then update the content of the page with some custom javascript.

As for the batch execution monitoring, I'd probably put an object within the session which gets updated as the batch script executes, then just ping back to an endpoint within Spring MVC which exposes the object from the session.

Your question is quite broad, and kind of involved, but hopefully this would give you a gist of what to do.

Comment: Thanks, it sounds like a good approach, I am only concerned about performance since the web client will query repeatedly and I am not sure how demanding that process will be under the hood. While I aim for something based on events, this one certainly seems an achievable approach.

Comment: You'd limit the updates to once every few seconds or so.  The backend query wouldn't be the problem, it'd be the DOM manipulation.